# vbscript to open file and save updated file

Tags: excel, vbscript

In the `vbs` I am trying to open a file, wait 20 seconds (or until updated), save, and close.... however when I run either of the the file does not update. Thank you :).

**Error with attempt 1:** Object required `wb`: line 5

**Attempt 1:**

```
Set xl  = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
  Set xlBook = GetObject("C:\path\to\file.xlsx")
  wscript.sleep(20000)
  wb.Save
  wb.Close
xl.Quit
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\file.xlsx")
objExcel.Calculate
objWorkbook.Save
```

Comment: The post is similar to attempt 1 without the loop. I posted the error I get running attempt 1. Thank you :).

Comment: Similar but not the same as you don't call `RefreshAll()`. Also, you call your `WorkBook` object `xlBook` but then try to access it using `wb` which won't exist hence the error - "Object required". Not to mention (in attempt 1), there is a complete disconnect between how you initialise the Excel instance and the workbook, unlike the working examples in the duplicate. Attempt 2 is closer to an actual working example.